# Is it possible to write $\prod_{x=1}^5 \sin(x) $ as a factorial?

Tags: factorial

$$\prod_{x=1}^5 \sin(x) $$ is actually equal as writing $$\sin(5)\cdot\sin(4)\cdot\sin(3)\cdot\sin(2)\cdot\sin(1)$$
I think there is no way of writing it as factorial? Or is there any?

Please help, Thanks

Comment: $\prod_{k=1}^5 \sin(k)\approx \Gamma(-5.98165)\approx \Gamma(-5.092)$

Comment: What do you mean by writing it as a factorial? What is the motivation for this question?

Comment: @Argon OP means that if you can write $f(x)=sin(x)!$ or is it an incorrect symbolism.

Comment: @Argon ... i wrote it for x; i am just thinking for sin(x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Pochhammer symbols, you have

$$P_n=\prod_{x=1}^n \sin(x)=2^{-(n+1)} e^{-\frac{1}{2} i n (n-\pi +1)} \left(-1;e^i\right){}_{n+1}
   \left(e^i;e^i\right){}_n$$ and so, you look for $k$ such that
$$k_n!=P_n \qquad \text{or better} \qquad \Gamma(k_n+1)=P_n$$

This is a difficult numerical problem since, as @K.defaoite already commented, the solution is not unique. But this is doable (do not wait for a closed form solution).